# Rename file return -1 with errno 18

Tags: linux

I am moving a file from /tmp/ folder to another path. I am using "rename" function to move  file to another path. But rename returns -1 and errno = 18 (Invalid cross-device link).
Error no 18 means:
"The directory containing the name newname must be on the same file system as the file (as indicated by the name oldname)"

Can someone suggest a way to move this file.

Answer (score 2):

If `rename()` is failing, you need to do the move manually, i.e. implement a copy-and-delete scheme.

Comment: I am creating a sqlite database in temp folder. Now I want to copy that file to another folder. Is there any sqlite command to rename the sqlite database file? I was trying with rename function. but it fails with error 18